# Connecting MongoDB from Mobile or Browser based Application

Tags: android, mongodb

My website uses Mongo as its database. I was wondering if the Java driver from the Mongo website applies to Android as well because I read that it wasn't supported.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simpy put it's not a good Idea for your Android app to connect to MongoDB **directly** in the first place.

You should be thinking as if it was just another web client and implement a RESTful interface for all the data you want to exchange or update. Look at [these links](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) as a possibility or otherwise roll your own interface.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB should be supported on Android since 2.9.0
Based on this : https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10006&version=11124

This may be helpful :
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-mongodb-tutorials/

Comment: Not very helpful. Please look at my answer supplied to this question and consider security and firewall considerations in a publicly accessible internet application.