# Mongodb to Android Application

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js, mongodb

I want to connect android application to Mongodb. I had installed Mongodb into my system but i don't know to connect with android.I tried mongo with java applicaion.can you help me?

Comment: May be this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554887/connecting-mongodb-from-android-app

Answer (score 0):

It is a very large question but,

The best way to achieve this is to create a restful webservice to access your mongodb database and also respond to clients with that service.

There are lots of choices to pick a framework for your restful webservice however, you can use [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) because of its ease of using.

1. First, deploy your jersey application as your backend application to
   your localhost or to some remote hosting provider as y.
2. Second, make http calls to your backend and fetch the data from
   mongodb in json format
3. Third, parse the json formatted data in your android application and show it on your layout.

Comment: our intention is when we run the android app in mobile  then the data will be saved in the mongodb? what is the basic idea or any other example could you please describe it

Comment: There is no local mongodb if this is what you are talking about. You can use couchbase-mobile which is a nosql database solution for mobile devices.

Comment: we need to store the data in mongo server not  locally.

Comment: my friend, as i said, you have to put some web server in front of your mongodb to serve your data. In your android application you will make http requests to this web server and you will parse the responses accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gunhan

Comment: public class MongoDBConnection1 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
  DB db = mongo.getDB("testdb");
  System.out.println(db);
 }
}
If i run the code i got the error follows how to rectify this

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/operation/OperationExecutor
 at com.aail.MongoDBConnection1.main(MongoDBConnection1.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.operation.OperationExecutor
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 1 more

Comment: Please take a look at this example http://jithinrajtanur.blogspot.com.tr/2015/06/restfull-api-using-javajersey-and.html