# MongoDB - Java | Use of MongoDB Java Driver to connect to mongoLab

Tags: java, php, android, mongodb, mlab

I am implementing an android application that uses mongoDB database that is stored in mLab. The way i am connecting to the database is with code in my android application as follows:

```
private MongoCollection<Document> getCollectionn(String link, String coll){
//link is: mongodb://<user>:<password>@ds<port>.mlab.com:<port>/<db>
    MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI(link);
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
    MongoDatabase db =  client.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());
    return db.getCollection(coll);
}
```

I was wondering if this is the best way to connect with the database. I am reading that it has performance and security issues. Would it be better, for example, to connect with the database via a php file that is stored in a server and get the results from my queries from there and use them in my application. Is there some other way?

**EDIT**

From mongoLab documentation they are saying the following:

mLab databases can be accessed by applications in two ways.

The first method - the one **we strongly recommend** - is to connect using one of the available MongoDB drivers. You do not need to use our API if you use the driver. In fact, using a driver provides better performance, better security, and more functionality.

The second method, documented in this article, is to connect via mLab’s RESTful Data API. Use this method only if you cannot connect using a MongoDB driver.

[Here](http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/#authentication) is the documentation to their API.

So why would someone suggest to use the RESTful API while mongoLab **strongly** recommends the mongo java driver? Is it because its about Android?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read this: [Connecting MongoDB from Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554887/connecting-mongodb-from-android-app)

Comment: I eddited my question :) Thanks again Blakes!

Comment: There is a physical limit to how many clients can connect to a database. If the database client is a mobile device, you'll hit a scalability issue with connections. Also difficult to secure database credentials if they're distributed with the mobile app. An app / api layer between mobile clients and the database that utilizes connection pooling is a better architecture. The SA question linked by @BlakesSeven talks about implementing such an app / api layer (RESTful API), it's not suggesting to use mLab's RESTful API. Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both answers helped to make a start.