# Android - MongoDb Application

Tags: android, mongodb

Looking for some information and advice on the best way to go about using and integrating MongoDb for an Android App I am trying to develop. Last I looked around there was not an actual Android-MongoDb API that I am aware of so I am curious how this could be implemented. One of the biggest issues I am thinking about is connectivity while out in the field without network access since the app will be collecting data and I am wondering what is the best way to store the data locally on the device in cache until either service becomes available, or at the end of the day, the user can then upload the data. Thanks.

Comment: Android has nice syncadapters so you can sync your local data with the server one when you have connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting MongoDB from Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554887/connecting-mongodb-from-android-app)