# Accessing MongoDB through Android app. Not Working

Tags: java, android, mongodb

Things I Have tried:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("MyPCName");

MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder().connectTimeout(3000);
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(address.getHostAddress(), 3001), builder.build());
        try {
            mongo.getAddress();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Mongo is down");
            mongo.close();
        }
```

Second try:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("MyPCName");
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI( "mongodb://"+address.getHostAddress()+":27017/"+TEST_SKETCH_APP );

MongoClient instance = MongoDatabaseConnection.getInstance(uri);
try {
            instance .getAddress();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Mongo is down");
            instance .close();
        }
```

FireWall configured properly :

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allowing mongod" dir=in action=allow program=" C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe"
```

But Still when I try to connect to do an insert operation I get this error message :

```
Timed out after 3000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=192.168.138.1:3001, type=Unknown, state=Connecting}]
```

I am doing the save operation in an AsyncTask. My mongo db server is running in the "MyPCName" computer. My Mongodb config has bind ip commented too. And I have also tried the bind Ip to keep this `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,***.***.***.*,0.0.0.0`
The '*' mark is the ip address which I get when I do a `address.getHostAddress()`.

I am now stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
MongoClientURI mongoUri  = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://Dbuser:dbpass@ds047692.mongolab.com:47692");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUri);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("testdb");
Set<String> collectionNames = db.getCollectionNames();
```

In addition, you should check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21555200/4810206.

Comment: Dont want to use a mongolab database, want to have a database in a local computer and make it a server later.