# MongoDB not running on iOS Unity Build

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, mongodb, unity-game-engine

Hi I am trying to query my Mongo Database by using a list of Facebook ID's as the parameter in order to return the list of users with corresponding accounts. The method works fine in the Unity Editor however when I run it on iOS I get a constructor error (I have set a blank default constructor in order to solve the issue however it still doesn't work)

**Error**

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Default constructor not found...ctor() of MongoDB.Driver.CommandResultSerializer'.
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes.BsonSerializerAttribute.CreateSerializer (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult] (MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection connection, System.String databaseName, IMongoCommand command) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.Ping (MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection connection) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.Connect () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect (TimeSpan timeout, MongoDB.Driver.ReadPreference readPreference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Tacticsoft.Examples.SimpleTableViewController.FriendsHighscoreHndlr (IGraphResult FBresult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Facebook.Unity.AsyncRequestString+<Start>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Rethrow as MongoConnectionException: Unable to connect to server XXX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXX: Method not found: 'Default constructor not found...ctor() of MongoDB.Driver.CommandResultSerializer'..
  at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect (TimeSpan timeout, MongoDB.Driver.ReadPreference readPreference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Tacticsoft.Examples.SimpleTableViewController.FriendsHighscoreHndlr (IGraphResult FBresult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Facebook.Unity.AsyncRequestString+<Start>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

**Initial Method**

```
 public void FetchData()
    {
        //data = Mongo.Instance.players.FindAll().ToList();
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            FB.API("me/friends", HttpMethod.GET, FriendsHighscoreHndlr);
        }
    }
```

**Callback Method**

```
public void FriendsHighscoreHndlr (IGraphResult FBresult)
{            
    var dict = Json.Deserialize(FBresult.ToString()) as Dictionary<string,object>;
    var friendList = new List<object>();
    friendList = (List<object>)(dict["data"]);

    int _friendCount = friendList.Count;
    Debug.Log("Found friends on FB, _friendCount ... " +_friendCount);
    List<string> friendIDsFromFB = new List<string>();
    for (int i=0; i<_friendCount; i++) {
        string friendFBID = getDataValueForKey( (Dictionary<string,object>)(friendList[i]), "id");
        string friendName =    getDataValueForKey( (Dictionary<string,object>)(friendList[i]), "name");
        Debug.Log( i +"/" +_friendCount +" " +friendFBID +" " +friendName);
        friendIDsFromFB.Add(friendFBID);
    }
    //friendIDsFromFB.Add(AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId);
    var query = Query.In("facebookID", BsonArray.Create(friendIDsFromFB));
    //Debug.Log(query);
    data = Mongo.Instance.players.Find(query).ToList();
}
```

**Data Value for Key Method**

```
private string getDataValueForKey(Dictionary<string, object> dict, string key) {
            object objectForKey;
            if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out objectForKey)) {
                return (string)objectForKey;
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

**Return Query Result**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("XXXXXX"),
    "facebookID" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "highScore" : 40501
}
```

Comment: Why are you using iOS to query a mongo database for 'friends'?

Comment: In all honesty you should not even be trying this. Database servers should not be directly accessed from mobile clients. It is far better practice to implement something along the lines of a RESTful API or other stateless service to act as the intermediary between the client and the database. Better for security, communication reliability and a whole host of reasons. Takes the weight off your client app as well. Ref: [Connecting MongoDB from Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554887/connecting-mongodb-from-android-app)

Comment: @Neil Thank you for saying what I was thinking but couldn't be bothered saying.

Comment: After digging around I found that `WWWForm` and `WWW` are built in classes within the Unity engine that could be used to create a RESTFul API Model. However there is little documentation on it. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: @Prad You don't need to create a REST API in Unity. You only want to consume it in your Unity/Android app. The actual API can be created using ASP.NET WebAPI, PHP, Java, etc.

Comment: This is all really about misunderstanding concepts. If you instead think of your iOS/Android/WindowsPhone ( even though it's just Winddows 10 now, right! ) application as a ***"fancy browser, with other optimized things"*** then maybe the parts of architecture are easier to understand. All your "client" really need know how to speak ( particularly with REST ) is basic HTTP  GET, POST, PUT etc, and then parsing data in the body in your favorite format. The API that talks to the database lives elsewhere. Just like building a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)